# Is there a simple way to change datadir of multiple redis-server on one machine?

Tags: redis, redis-server

I am running multiple instances of redis servers on my machine for different projects, I am wondering if there is a flag I can add on startup for each to specify the datadir for the the persistent file location? All solutions I have found to date are for changing the base config.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can override the configuration in the configuration file during startup like this:

```
redis-server redis.conf --port 6380 --loglevel verbose --dir /var/logs/
```

All configurations will be taken from the config file, but the configurations of port, loglevel and dir will be over-ridden